# How to return resultset from MySQL Stored Procedure using prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursors, prepared-statement

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE List_IL()

BEGIN

  DECLARE Project_Number_val VARCHAR( 255 );
  DECLARE Temp_List_val VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE Project_List_val VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE FoundCount INT;
  DECLARE Project_Number INT;
  DECLARE db_Name VARCHAR(255);



  DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
  DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;


  DECLARE   projects_cur    CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  Project_Id
    FROM    Project_Details;


  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET no_more_rows = TRUE;


  OPEN projects_cur;
  select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;

  the_loop: LOOP

    FETCH  projects_cur
    INTO   Project_Number_val;


    IF no_more_rows THEN
        CLOSE projects_cur;
        LEAVE the_loop;
    END IF;


SET Project_List_val = CONCAT(Project_Number_val, '_List');
SET db_Name='panel';


SELECT COUNT(1) INTO  FoundCount  FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = `db_Name`  AND table_name = `Project_List_val`;

 IF FoundCount = 1 THEN
SET @Project_Number=Project_Number_val;

SET @sql = CONCAT(' SELECT Panel_Id,', Project_Number_val,'
                    FROM ', @Project_List_val,' Where status=1');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;

    SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1;
  END LOOP the_loop;


END $$
```

In the above stored procedure How can I get the all the rows selected during execution of prepared statement and after the loop terminates I want to return the entire result set whichever calls the stored procedure. Can you please help me how to do this?

Comment: Can you please explain what are you doing in line "SELECT COUNT(1) INTO  FoundCount  FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = `db_Name`  AND table_name = `Project_List_val`;
" and after that line.

Comment: I'm just checking whether that particualr table exist in db or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you a solution create a log table like this

```
CREATE TABLE log_records
(
Panel_Id INT,
Project_Number_val VARCHAR(255)
);
```

In your code add lines as follows here i will insert those record into log_table which you was selecting please look the line /**Added by abdul */

```
    IF FoundCount = 1 THEN
        SET @Project_Number=Project_Number_val;

        SET @sql = CONCAT(' SELECT Panel_Id,', Project_Number_val,'    FROM ', @Project_List_val,' Where status=1');


    /*--Added by Abdul*/
        SET @insert_sql = CONCAT ('INSERT INTO log_records' ,'SELECT Panel_Id,', Project_Number_val,'    FROM ', @Project_List_val,' Where status=1');
        PREPARE stmt_insert FROM @insert_sql;
        EXECUTE stmt_insert;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt_insert; 
    /**--End**/     

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END IF;
```

And then where loop end add line

```
SELECT * FROM log_records;
```

This will give you the desired result.

Also Write one line in your code before you open the cursor otherwise each procedure call will be appending data in that table.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE log_table;
```

Comment: does this works for you ?

Comment: Yes, Initially I was doing the same but wanted do thing differently.